# Create seperate NuGet package for different projects in a Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, clr, .net-6.0

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution containing dot net 6.0 and clr:netcore projects.

Most of the projects depend on other projects as a reference using dependency injection (not project reference).

I need to create NuGet packages for all projects separately.

Is there any way, rather than writing a script, to do it at once?

What i am thinking of is having a separate `.nuspec` file for each project and running a script to create packages with `dotnet pack` command.

Anyone have such an experience?

Comment: Are you sure this is for C++, not C#?

Comment: Dependency injection is a code pattern, not a way of referencing assemblies

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, this works with c++ clr:netcore projects.

Comment: @Ahmadi yes, wanted to make sure. though my wording was far from perfect)

Comment: We can use dotnet pack ***.sln to create separate NuGet packages for different projects in the solution in C#, but C++ doesn't seem to be able to do this at once.